# Calling a generic method in a loop with different types known at compile time

Tags: c#, generics

Let's consider a method in an interface :

```
public Interface IA {
    T[] Get<T>() where T : IB;
}
```

In another place I would like to call this method n times for n types *which are known at compile time*. The following code illustrates my **intention**.

```
foreach(Type t in new Type[] { typeof(X), typeof(Y), typeof(Z) }) 
{
    InterfaceXYZImplement[] arr = c.Resolve<IA>().Get<t>();
    //...more here
}
```

Now, the `foreach` loop obviously makes the type become a run-time value so I would have to use `MakeGenericMethod`.

Is there a way to write the code in such a way that I can have the code executed for `X`, `Y` and `Z`, but call the method written only once?

Wrapping the code in a method would only move the problem upwards (which is a partial solution but not the ultimate one, heh).

Comment: Why not just call them one by one? Are the types known at compile time every changing?

Comment: I'm not realy clear on what "call the method written only once" means, and what's wrong with [@mrtofigh's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10429266) - could you elaborate? What's wrong with using `MakeGenericMethod` ?

Comment: @leppie Because the list may be used somewhere else as in: a have a list of types store in file and different pieces of the system do things for these types. When add a type I need find all the places where I 'call them one by one'.

Comment: @AakashM 1. I meant call the method once not 3 times. 2. MakeGenericMethod takes a string and strings are evil.

Comment: Well, *something's* got to happen `n` times if there are `n` types, I'm not sure why you don't want that something to be a method call. And if you don't want to hardcode the method name to pass to `MakeGenericMethod`, you can play around with a `delegate` and an `Expression`.

Answer (score 3):

You could achieve this using some helper method that makes quite a few assumptions and uses the new `dynamic` keyword in .NET4.

Basically, the solution makes use of the feature of the DLR to correctly infer the type to be used for a generic method, when the parameter that uses the type is a `dynamic`. For this to work, you will need two helper methods:

```
IB[] Get(IA a, Type t)
{
    dynamic dummy = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
    return Get(a, dummy);
}

T[] Get<T>(IA a, T dummy) where T : IB
{
    return a.Get<T>();
}
```

And your code would call the first of those helper methods:

```
foreach(var t in new Type[] { typeof(X), typeof(Y), typeof(Z) })
{
    IB[] arr = Get(c.Resolve<IA>(), t);
    // do more stuff here
}
```

As you can see, this approach has several draw backs:

1. For each type in the loop, a new instance is created via `Activator.CreateInstance(t)`. This line makes the assumption that there exists a public parameterless constructor that can be used and that this constructor doesn't do anything heavy.
2. If any of the types in the loop doesn't implement `IB` this code will throw an exception at runtime. There will be no compile error.
3. The result is always an array of `IB` instances, not an array of the specific type.

Answer (score 3):

Define an extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void Get<T>(this IA a, Action<T[]> action, params Type[] types) where T : IB
    {
        foreach (var type in types)
        {
            var method = a.GetType().GetMethod("Get").MakeGenericMethod(type);
            var ts = (T[])method.Invoke(a, null);
            action(ts);
        }
    }
}
```

Use:

```
a.Get(arr => { 
   // work on result
}, typeof(X), typeof(Y), typeof(Z));
```

Comment: Magic string! Aaaaaah! Casting! Aaaah!